# Trigger a file input to open via javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload

So I have an input, something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

I want to get the file open dialog to popup via javascript. I have tried things like this:

```
$('file').click();
```

(that's assuming I'm using something like prototype/mootools/jquery). However, this doesn't seem to do anything. Is there anyway I can trigger the click event for the file input without the user being forced to interact with the input directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('file').click()
```

This works (in Chrome 8). You just need to make sure it's not set to display: none;

An easy solution is to position it absolute and then set left to something like -1000px.

Answer (score 3):

I recall this is not possible due to it being a security feature. In fact, I'm pretty sure the button for the file browsing dialog does not even show up in the DOM (the field shows up, but not the button, which the browser renders automatically)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know opening the file open dialog from javascript is blocked for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC browsers don't allow this as a precaution mechanism. A script shouldn't be able to automatically upload a file in some way and tinkering with the File Open-dialog would be one of those ways.

Obviously this is bad in some situations...

Comment: well I don't plan on it automatically opening the file. I just want the input to look different. What I was trying was to hide the file input, and have a link the user can click to popup the file open dialog. I understand security concerns, but it makes that thing ugly and hackish :D