# Programmatically initiate file selection window on igUpload widget

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui

- Let's pretend we have to make a simple web page that allows users to upload files on the server.
- When a user arrives on the page, the files selection window has to open automatically.
- The user has to be able to select and upload multiple files at once.

igUpload control does fit nicely in this scenario.

Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to programmatically display the browse window to select a file for upload, without having to click the Upload File button. I'm using Ignite UI 13.2, which documentation could be found [here](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2013.2/ui.igupload) and there is a  related question from Infragistics forum [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/104201.aspx).

I've seen few examples, where overrides of private methods are suggested in order to modify default behavior, but currently, I couldn't find the appropriate place to intervene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

igUpload is using `<input type="file"/>` and in most browsers it is not allowed opening file selections window( via javascript ) because of security reason( [Trigger a file input to open via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516414/trigger-a-file-input-to-open-via-javascript)) . Probalby only IE allows you to achieve this - you can try:

```
var id = "upload";
$('#' + id).igUpload();
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#' + id + '_ibb_fp').click();
}, 0);
```